# How to get a shopping cart price rule name if I know the id of a rule in product page-View.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to display a shoping cart price rule name in a product page, if I know an ID of that rule?

Is there an easy way? I can access atributes, but i am first time dealling with cart rules in product page.

I am using Magento 1.9.2.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(<Rule_Id>);
$rule_name=$rule->getName();
```